# Springframework JAXB Marshalling Exception in IE not in Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, spring, jaxb

Hi I get this marhshalling exception when I call a service using IE but it works fine with Firefox.

> DEBUG -
>   AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(108)
>   | Resolving exception from handler
>   [org.dfci.cccb.services.SearchServiceImpl@a832ce5]:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not marshal
>   [org.dfci.cccb.domain.QueryResult@6ecff10d]:
>   null; nested exception is
>   javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2:
>   class
>   org.dfci.cccb.domain.hivseqdb.Sequence
>   nor any of its super class is known to
>   this context.
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class
>   org.dfci.cccb.domain.hivseqdb.Sequence
>   nor any of its super class is known to
>   this context.]

I have a marshalling bean configured like so:

```
<bean id="SequenceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>org.dfci.cccb.domain.hivseqdb.Sequence</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The only thing I can think of is that IE is sending addtional accept encoding fields that is interfering with the Marhshalling.

Comment: Does this happen with all versions of IE?  You might try using Fiddler to capture the request and compare them in IE vs Firefox to see if IE is actually sending something different to the server.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/